# Can't Load Data to ComboBox C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, combobox

I Inserted Data to `ComboBox` using Folloowing Code in `FormLoad Block`

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        SelectCategoryComboBox.Items.Clear();
        string query = "SELECT CategoryName FROM CategoryTable";
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader sdr = new SqlCommand(query, con).ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            SelectCategoryComboBox.Items.Add(sdr.GetValue(0).ToString());
        }

    }
}
catch
{
    StatusLabel.Text = "An error occured while loading Data";
}
finally
{
    SelectCategoryComboBox.SelectedItem = null;
    SelectCategoryComboBox.SelectedText = "Choose Category";
}
```

it does the Job. in the Form You can Create a Category and Delete By Selecting The Name of the category from `ComboBox` [Here is a ScreenShot the Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFdR2.png). I used the following code to Delete and Load the items to ComboBox after Deleting.

```
try
{
    String conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mfcdb"].ConnectionString;
    String query = "DELETE FROM CategoryTable WHERE CategoryName='" + SelectCategoryComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    StatusLabel.Text = "You have successfully deleted " + SelectCategoryComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() + " Category";
}
catch
{
    StatusLabel.Text = "An Error occured while deleting " + SelectCategoryComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() + " Category";
}
finally
{
    try
    {
        SelectCategoryComboBox.Items.Clear();
        String conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mfcdb"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {


            string query = "SELECT CategoryName FROM CategoryTable";
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader sdr = new SqlCommand(query, con).ExecuteReader();
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                SelectCategoryComboBox.Items.Add(sdr.GetValue(0).ToString());
            }

        }
    }
    catch
    {
        StatusLabel.Text = "An error occured while loading Data";
    }
    finally
    {
        SelectCategoryComboBox.SelectedItem = null;
        SelectCategoryComboBox.SelectedText = "Choose Category";
    }
```

code for Creating new item Given below

```
 if (CategoryNameText.Text == "")
            {
                StatusLabel.Text = "You have to provide a name to create a category";
            }
            else
            {
                String conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mfcdb"].ConnectionString;
                String query = "INSERT INTO CategoryTable(CategoryName) VALUES('" + CategoryNameText.Text + "')";
                try
                {
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    StatusLabel.Text = "You have successfully created " + CategoryNameText.Text + " Category";

                    try
                    {
                        using (SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(conString))
                        {
                            string locQuery = "SELECT CategoryName,Categoryid FROM CategoryTable";
                            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(locQuery, scon);
                            scon.Open();
                            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                            da.Fill(ds, "CategoryTable");
                            SelectCategoryComboBox.ValueMember = "Categoryid";
                            SelectCategoryComboBox.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
                            SelectCategoryComboBox.DataSource = ds.Tables["CategoryTable"];
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(3000);
                        StatusLabel.Text = "An Error Occured while Loading Data!";
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        SelectCategoryComboBox.SelectedItem = null;
                        SelectCategoryComboBox.SelectedText = "Choose Category";
                    }
                    CategoryNameText.Focus();
                }
                catch
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    StatusLabel.Text = ("An ERROR occured While creating category!");
                }
                finally
                {
                    CategoryNameText.Text = "Enter Category Name";
                }

            }
        }
```

This Code Deletes Items Perfectly.But If I delete an Item Which is Already in the `ComboBox`, it does the Job i.e it deletes and Load the Remaining items to `ComboBox`.but, if I Created an Item,and Deleted it Before Closing the Form, it deletes the item.But Fails to Load the remaining items.it shows all the items already exist in the `ComboBox` Before Deleting. Would be a great help if you can help me solve this problem. Here `SelectCategoryComboBox` is the Name of the `ComboBox`.

Comment: It seems that you mentioned that you want to create an Item, but I can't see the related code. can you provide it? Let me test it.

Comment: Question Updated with the requested Code

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem occur in the following sentence.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO CategoryTable(CategoryName) VALUES('" + CategoryNameText.Text + "')";
```

I have two solutions.

First, Please set the Allow nulls for other field.
Like the following:
[image]

Second, you can use the following code to replace the original code.

```
string query = string.Format("INSERT INTO Student(CategoryName, CategoryId, Age) VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}')",textBox1.Text,textBox2.Text,textBox3.Text);
```

Comment: I made `Identity Specification = True` ,On DB for that Column The Problem you mentioned is not Causing my Error

Answer (score 0):

I found What went Wrong...
Change Following Code

```
using (SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(conString))
                        {
                            string locQuery = "SELECT CategoryName,Categoryid FROM CategoryTable";
                            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(locQuery, scon);
                            scon.Open();
                            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                            da.Fill(ds, "CategoryTable");
                            SelectCategoryComboBox.ValueMember = "Categoryid";
                            SelectCategoryComboBox.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
                            SelectCategoryComboBox.DataSource = ds.Tables["CategoryTable"];
                        }
```

To

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
                        {
                            SelectCategoryComboBox.Items.Clear();
                            string squery = "SELECT CategoryName FROM CategoryTable";
                            con.Open();
                            SqlDataReader sdr = new SqlCommand(squery, con).ExecuteReader();
                            while (sdr.Read())
                            {
                                SelectCategoryComboBox.Items.Add(sdr.GetValue(0).ToString());
                            }

                        }
```

it Worked for me.

Comment: It seems that your problem has been solved. Then, you could click '✔' to mark it as the best answer so that it will help other members to find the solution quickly if they face the similar issue.